# multiple cs files for multiple asp.net files

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I've got an uncompiled site using C#.  I've got 6 files sharing a bunch of functions in random classes.  I'd like to move these into a more logical separation, but I don't see how to refer to classes in another cs file.

Ideally, I'd separate these into cs files into logical pieces like shoppingcart class in one file, routine functions in another, etc.  And all 6 files can refer to any of the separated cs files.

Is this even possible if we don't compile them?

update:

Ok, so my code might look like this and the syntax for the ShoppingCart.cart is not correct but it's an example of how I'd like this to work:

default.aspx.cs:

```
using ShoppingCart;

public partial class DefaultPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected void page_load()
  {
    ShoppingCart.cart.CheckCart("newguy");
  }
```

shoppingcart.cs:

```
namespace ShoppingCart
{
 public partial class cart : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    public string CheckCart(string cartname)
    {
      return "test";
    }
```

etc

Comment: What do you mean you don't see how to refer to classes in another cs file?

Comment: Code samples would help with understanding what you are talking about.

Comment: You seem to be using a Web Site "project", created by File->New Web Site. This explains why nobody knows what you're talking about. Don't use those. They are different from everything else in Visual Studio, and the only people who know how they work are those who are stuck working with them.

Comment: Nope.  I am not using a project. These are loose files, no project or anything.

Comment: Why would "cart" descend from Page?  If you really want to do that, then it seems likely that DefaultPage should descend from "cart"...

Comment: it doesn't matter.  this is a sample.  I understand what you mean, but it doesn't help answer the root question here.

Comment: @JonHiggens: everything in .net is grouped into one project type or another.  If your files are "loose" as you say, then you are dealing with a "web site project" and really should take John's recommendation into consideration.

Comment: Ok.  I'm lost.  In that case, how do I group these files together without using a 'web site project' (which I'm not using currently.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this even possible if we don't compile them?

This question doesn't make sense.

A code file references another one through a combination of `namespace`'s and the `using` directive.

Your example kind of shows this.  However, it's completely invalid code (won't compile) because you don't have an instance of the cart class to reference.  It was never instantiated.

Which means you need to mark the `CheckCart` method as static, turn the cart class into a singleton, or make DefaultPage descend from cart.

Regardless, the ShoppingCart namespace needs to be compiled, which means those 6 files you are talking about need to be grouped into an assembly OR be made part of your main project in order to get the code to run.

Web Site Projects do some of this completely behind the scenes if you just drop the code into the app_code folder.  However, WSP's do a number of other unexpected things which if you've worked with them for any length of time you'll come to find out are utter garbage.

So, building on John's comment, convert it to a Web Application Project.  For the additional code you have the option of creating a separate assembly project and throwing it in there or simply leaving it in sub folders of the main project.

Comment: Thanks, I think the last two paragraphs should really help. I appreciate the in-depth answer.

Answer (score 1):

Keep them in the same namespace. This will let you call other classes from other classes......

And your cs-files *do* get compiled. It just happens under the hood ;)

Answer (score 1):

if you need to separate the business logic from UI, one option is creating separate class library for business logic and call those methods from UI layer. following link will help you

[Creating a Web Application Project with a Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668164.aspx)

Or you can keep them in same project but make sure you are using same namespace for all the classes.

Comment: I think he's using a web site "project".